# AWS Beanstalk with Ruby 2.6 on AMI1 - Update from Puma 4.3.7 to Puma 5.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I've a strange behaviour on my **AWS Beanstalk Ruby app**.

I am on a Ruby platform with **Linux AMI1** (I cannot upgrade to the AMI2 for too many errors, I will plan it for the late '21, but this is another story) last version, so **Ruby 2.6**.

I tried to update my **Puma from 4.3.7 to 5.1.1** in gemfile and locally all works fine.

I add my **puma.rb** config file:

```
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count
worker_timeout 3600 if ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV", "development") == "development"
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }
plugin :tmp_restart
```

When I deploy it, I have a strange behaviour, the deploy works fine but at the end I have **Puma not working** and **CPU at 100%** with even the message:

*100 % of CPU is in use.
Following services are not running: application.*

I tried to read logs but no luck, I didn't find any particular error except than Puma is not working.
Can someone help me?

I can provide every info do you need for this, I'm really stucked!

Thanks a lot

Comment: What size instance are you using? If you are using a small instance size, you might try increasing it to see if that is part of the issue.

Comment: I tried even on a large machine, but the CPU problem is only a "false flag" imho. The problem is that Puma is not starting and the instance continuously try to restart the process.

Comment: Can you post your Puma config? Have you reviewed the changelog (https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/v5.1.1/History.md) and the Puma 5 upgrade documentation (https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/v5.1.1/5.0-Upgrade.md)? For example, daemonization was removed in Puma 5.

Comment: Hi @dentarg, I added the Puma config file in the question. Thanks for the help.